# Best Research Documentation Habit for Computational Physics Research

Tags: cosmology, soft-question, computational-physics, software, gravitational-lensing

I am currently doing research in a subset of the field of gravitational lensing called weak lensing. I am simulating blended galaxy profiles and creating an algorithm to extract the true parameters I created my image with. I am then assessing the accuracy of my algorithm.

Since this is my first venture in creating code modules, specifically in python, I am wondering how other researchers have used resources to create the best kind of documentation for work that is fundamentally computational, not experimental.

For example, do I put all my work in a Google logbook? Or do I use Ipython notebook to generate PDF's? I've had a tremendously hard time finding suitable materials.

Comment: I program CFD simmulations for an heavy ion physics group. My small experience tells me that a combination of latex for writing the ideas and algorithms and (not numerous) comments on the code are good enough for just myself, though a full fledge pdf with a manual, algorithms and examples is necessary if other people are going to use your code. The best documentation is allways going to be good design of the interfaces, which if properly done, its a documentation by itself

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code maintenance and not physics.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about documenting software.

Comment: Related: http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/21276/ , http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/83/

Comment: I'm weakly in favor of this being on-topic as far as the coding/documentation angle is concerned (we [allow computational stuff already](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5603/adding-computational-science-to-the-list-of-on-topic-items-in-the-help-center)), especially if the focus is on physics-specific techniques. *If* this is off-topic, IMO it should be because it solicits opinions. Perhaps we can take this to [meta](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: This may seem off-topic at first glance but the problem of code management and documentation is about knowing how to use your tools.  If this was about how best to care for a beam splitter on an optics bench would this be off-topic?  And certainly from the perspective of a group/collaboration leader in any data heavy physics it is important. Coding and doc management tools are used by computational physicists, high-energy physicists, and other groups in physics all the time.  If the tools of physics are on-topic then question most certainly is as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this question is primarily opinion based.  Different people keep different systems, but I'll share my system.

To start, version control is *absolutely* essential.  I recommend [git](http://git-scm.com/).  Here are some nice resources:

- [Git for Scientists](http://nyuccl.org/pages/GitTutorial/) - an overview aimed at scientists
- [Atlassian Git tutorials](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorial) - a nice overview and discussion of different *strategies* for using git.
- [Try Git](https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1) - A browser based tutorial that actually has you issuing git commands, this has been useful for our new group members.

In general, I tend to believe git is used best if you commit early and often, and in particular if you branch early and often.

As for python resources in general, I can't help but recommend:

- [Scientific Python Lectures](https://github.com/jrjohansson/scientific-python-lectures) - Nice overview of python for scientific audiences and the larger python ecosystem (numpy, scipy, matplotlib, etc)
- [Scipy-lectures](http://scipy-lectures.github.io/index.html) - an absolutely fabulous set of resources on the scipy ecosystem.  Very handy resource
- [anaconda](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/) - a scientific python *distribution* that contains all of the useful packages in one install.  If you have an academic email, be sure to apply for the free academic license and the `accelerate` package which will give you scipy/numpy properly linked against intel mkl so that it is fast.
- [enthought canopy](https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/) - another scientific python distribution with academic licenses
- [python(xy)](https://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/) - yet another scientific distribution

Back to the question at hand.  For the most part, when I am working on a project, I keep a directory tree that looks like:

```
project/
├── .git/ - I use git for version control
├── code/ - where my main code lives
├── data/ - where my data files live, this is not checked into version control
├── scripts/ - contains scripts to generate my outputs, figures
├── output/ - holds my generated figures and results
├── Makefile - used to build notes, and save parameter choices for scripts
└── notes/ - contains markdown notes
```

I use as a template for my .gitignore, the [Python.gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Python.gitignore) in the [gitignore repository](https://github.com/github/gitignore/), but I additionally ignore the `data/` folder as I don't want to check in large files.  I instead aim to make my data reproducible from my scripts.  Not only does this keep my git repo small and fast by not checking in large data files, but it keeps me honest, ensuring that my results are themselves generated by scripts that are checked into the repository.

For `notes/` I tend to use a mix of [ipython notebooks](http://ipython.org/notebook.html) with healthy markdown sections explaining things and demonstrating code, and plenty of [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/) equations.  Additionally I keep some small [markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) files that contain derivations and notes on literature I read, with lots of [LaTeX](http://www.latex-project.org/) sprinkled in for equations.  I would just use LaTeX files themselves, but I found the start up associated with creating a new one a bit high, which meant didn't take as many notes as I'd like.  Markdown on the other hand is simple to write, which prevents any excuse for not taking notes.  I use [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) to convert these markdown files to nice readable pdfs with equations or html pages.  I automate this in my `Makefile`, as well as rules for generating figures or certain results once I've figured something out.  For the notes bit, I have part of the Makefile look like this:

```
MDS := $(wildcard notes/*.md)
    NBS := $(wildcard notes/*.ipynb)
MDHTMLS := $(patsubst notes/%.md,notes/html/%.html,$(MDS))
NBHTMLS := $(patsubst notes/%.ipynb,notes/html/%.html,$(NBS))

notes: $(MDHTMLS) $(NBHTMLS)

.PHONY: serve cleannotes
serve:
        cd notes/html && python -m SimpleHTTPServer
cleannotes:
        rm -rf notes/html

notes/html/%.html: notes/%.md notes/html
        pandoc -s -c markdown.css --mathjax="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML" --standalone -o $@ $< 
notes/html/%.html: notes/%.ipynb notes/html
        ipython nbconvert --to html --output $(basename $@) $< 
notes/html:
        mkdir -p notes/html
```

This enables me to use `make notes` to build my notes, and `make serve` to serve them up at `http://localhost:8000/`

Additionally, to be explicit, I also add lines to by `Makefile` specifying particular arguments I give to my scripts or other scripts in order to generate or manipulate my data.  i.e.:

```
output/swirl.dat: scripts/simulation.py
    python $< -N 1000 -a 10 -v --otherparam 1.324 > $@
```

So that I can clearly see how I generated my outputs and automatically regenerate them if I make changes to the scripts.

Again, as I say, this is just my opinion, but it has worked well for me so far.

Comment: Version control for a single developer project? Isn't that a bit, um, unnecessary? It's not like there's competing updates in a merge (just your own), so there really isn't much use, IMO, of having git or svn or whatever else one might use.

Comment: @KyleKanos but having the complete history of the project is indispensable. Overhead in terms of my time is minimal. Git branching alone, allowing you to maintain your own set of alternative universes is tremendously useful. It gives me peace of mind (backups to a git server), freedom to experiment (by switching branches), and makes it stupid simple to collaborate with others in my group our outside.

Comment: @KyleKanos Version control can come in mighty handy when trying to locate regression bugs, even for a single user.

Comment: I would like to add that you should also somehow manage (save) the inputs to the program. It is quite usual to have dozens or hundreds of parameters in a computational problem, so using version control or something similar if iterating through different inputs might be useful (more typically perhaps one creates different folders for each run; I'd be interested if someone has a better way of documenting used inputs, though).

Comment: @alarge I didn't make this explicit, but I tend to add `.PHONY` lines to my `Makefile` with my particular inputs to generate particular results.

Comment: Makefile? CMake is so much better...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Python then I would recommend [Sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/) and [git](http://git-scm.com/).  Check your code into git so you have a history of your work and use Sphinx to generate the documentation off your code.  This is a common combination and should meet most of your documentation needs.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to speak about version control. They are absolutely essential to keep a decent track of the History of the code